# Adding horizontal and vertical lines , matrix

Tags: tables

```
A= [0.7577    0.7060    0.8235    0.4387    0.4898
        0.7431    0.0318    0.6948    0.3816    0.4456
        0.3922    0.2769    0.3171    0.7655    0.6463
        0.6555    0.0462    0.9502    0.7952    0.7094
        0.1712    0.0971    0.0344    0.1869    0.7547]
    latex_table = latex(sym(A));
    I save it as eqA.
    equations1.tex
        \newcommand{\eqA}{
                \left(
                        \begin{array}{ccccc}
                      \frac{6825116339432507}{9007199254740992} & 
                      \frac{6359497797823013}{9007199254740992} & 
                      \frac{3708524368810113}{4503599627370496} & 
                      \frac{987964467329731}{2251799813685248} & 
                      \frac{4411405500742427}{9007199254740992}\\ 
                      \frac{6693542213068579}{9007199254740992} & 
                      \frac{71681197541747}{2251799813685248} & 
                      \frac{6258459855040489}{9007199254740992} & 
                      \frac{859193262592067}{2251799813685248} & 
                      \frac{1003370923741521}{2251799813685248}\\ 
                      \frac{55201045594335}{140737488355328} & 
                      \frac{2494300503760379}{9007199254740992} & 
                      \frac{2856178200482939}{9007199254740992} & 
                      \frac{1723790560926853}{2251799813685248} & 
                      \frac{2910735031501795}{4503599627370496}\\ 
                      \frac{2952009981953243}{4503599627370496} & 
                      \frac{415874915283285}{9007199254740992} & 
                      \frac{8558839330135289}{9007199254740992} & 
                      \frac{3581261978445933}{4503599627370496} & 
                      \frac{6389390375844301}{9007199254740992}\\ 
                      \frac{770956303438939}{4503599627370496} & 
                      \frac{874885307559191}{9007199254740992} & 
                      \frac{77565677658637}{2251799813685248} & 
                      \frac{1683198784473707}{9007199254740992} & 
                      \frac{6797613319514473}{9007199254740992}
                  \end{array}
                          \right)
        }

    //latex
    \documentclass{article}
    \input{equations1}

    \begin{document}
        Here we have a nice matrix:
        \[
            \eqA{}
        \]

    \end{document}
```

How can I add horizontal and vertical lines and label column and rows of the table. The contents of the table should be updated every time by input eqA.
please see image[image]

Comment: There are other ways of getting a matrix from Matlab to a LaTeX table, e.g. http://www.mathworks.de/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4894-matrix2latex See if that does all you want. (It may not work with symbolic stuff, so you won't get the fractions, but from your other question it seems you're after decimals anyway.)

Comment: @  Torbjørn Thanx for ur reply. How can I change your comments as answer, so that I can click this question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used mathworks.de/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4894-matrix2latex and it works well.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `\hline` between the rows to get horizontal lines and `|` in the array preamble to specify vertical lines. As (again) you have not posted an example that may be run locally I haven't shown the result of adding these.

```
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
a&b\\
\hline
x&y\\
\hline
\end{array}
```

is a 2x2 example with horizontal and vertical rules.